# Ruby on Rails - Bullet Gem. Add to your query: .includes([:author])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an N+1 Query issue, but I dont understand how to fix the issue.

I have a User model, Post model and Comment Model.

```
User has many posts 
User has many comments 

Post belongs to User
Post has many Comments 

Comments belong to user 
Comment belongs to post
```

In my post controller, I have

```
def index
    @posts = Post.includes(:author).where(author_id: params[:user_id])
end


def show
    @post = Post.includes(:author).find(params[:id])
end
```

When I load the Posts show view below...
[image]

I get these two warnings from Bullet Gem

```
user: espada
GET /users/2/posts/6
USE eager loading detected
  Comment => [:author]
  Add to your query: .includes([:author])
Call stack

user: espada
GET /users/2/posts/6
USE eager loading detected
  Comment => [:post]
  Add to your query: .includes([:post])
Call stack
```

I have tried to add the two .includes in various actions, tried many things for the past 5 hours...nothing works. At this point, I want to understand where do I add those two includes?

And how does one interpret that message?

Comment: what do you mean by the author here? is it User ?

Comment: can you also post your html views?

Comment: Hi @Giridharan, in my post model I have `belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'` to take care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5861424/o-larkin) who mentioned that the problem could be in the view, I went and looked at my Post index and Post show view.

In my post show and index views, I was rendering a partial for the comments with

```
<%= render partial: "shared/post/comment_card", locals: { post: @post, comments: @post.comments} %>
```

In my comment card I had a delete button

```
<%= button_to "Delete Comment", user_post_comment_path(comment.author, comment.post, comment), 
      method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

That is where the warning was coming from when I get the post for each comment. I realized that since I had passed in the post via locals I could write my delete button as

```
<%= button_to "Delete Comment", user_post_comment_path(comment.author, post, comment), 
          method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

That fixed that error.

However, I also had to change my show action because trying to get a post without comments was raising a warning, so I wrote it as

```
  def show
    @post = Post.includes(:author).find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.includes(:author, comments: [:author]).find(params[:id]) if @post.comments.any?
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Its showing an error on the comments model

Try This

```
def index
    @posts = Post.includes(:author, comments: %i[author post]).where(author_id: params[:user_id])
end


def show
    @post = Post.includes(:author, comments: %i[author post]).find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Ley me try that and get back to you.

Comment: I tried that. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a dependency on comments, not on posts. So you have to include it like this.

```rb
Post.includes(:author, comments: [:author, :post]).find(params[:id])
```

Comment: I put your suggestion in the show action ... One of the errrors is gone, but I still have one warning 

`user: espada
GET /users/2/posts
USE eager loading detected
  Comment => [:post]
  Add to your query: .includes([:post])
Call stack`

I did not use that in the index action, because when I do I get another warning 


`user: espada
GET /users/2/posts
AVOID eager loading detected
  Post => [:comments]
  Remove from your query: .includes([:comments])
Call stack`

Comment: chances are you're calling something from views that is not part of this query, can you post those? @Ben

Comment: Is it okay if I share the repo link rather  than post the post index view and the post show view ? 

Here is the repo link [Repo link](https://github.com/Benmuiruri/community-blog)